# Why LINQ to Entities throw an Error in this select statement?

Tags: linq, select

I have two selects which are quite the same, but one of them (`getBranchsForUser`) throws an error.

```
public User GetUserByUsername(string username) 
{
    var db = new AdventureWorksEntities();
    User user = (from u in db.tabUser 
                 where u.strUsername.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                 select new User 
                            { 
                               strUsername = u.strUsername,  
                               intID = u.intUserID,   
                            }
                ).FirstOrDefault();
    user.branchsList = getBranchsForUser(user.intID);
    return user;
}

public List<Branch> getBranchsForUser(int userID)
{
  var db = new AdventureWorksEntities();
  List<Branch> branchsList = (from u in db.tabBranchs
                              where u.intUserID.Equals(userID)
                              select new Branch
                                         {
                                            dblGoal = u.dblGoal,
                                            intNbOfGradeForAYear = u.IntNBOfGradeForAYear,
                                            strName = u.strName
                                         }
                             ).ToList();
  return branchsList;
}
```

I get the following error in getBranchsForUser method :

> [System.NotSupportedException] {"The specified type member 'intUserID' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."}
>   System.NotSupportedException

Why don't I get it too for my `GetUserByUsername` method? (I do the same thing)

**EDIT** 
Table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tabBranchs] (
[intBranchID]          INT        NOT NULL,
[intUserID]            INT        NOT NULL,
[strName]              TEXT       NOT NULL,
[dblGoal]              FLOAT (53) NULL,
[IntNBOfGradeForAYear] INT        NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tabBranchs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([intBranchID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_tabBranchs_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([intUserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tabUser] ([intUserID])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tabUser] (
    [intUserID]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [strUsername] VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [strPassword] VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tabUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([intUserID] ASC)
);
```

**EDIT 2**

```
    public class Branch {
    public string strName { get; set; }
    public List<Mark> markList { get; set; }
    public double dblAverage { get; set; }
    public double? dblGoal { get; set; }
    public bool bHasGoal { get; set; }
    public int intNbOfGradeForAYear { get; set; }

    public Branch(){}

    public Branch(string branchName, double goal, int nbOfNotes)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.strName = branchName;
        this.dblGoal = goal;
        bHasGoal = true;
        this.intNbOfGradeForAYear = nbOfNotes;
    }
```

Comment: Is the property `intUserID` mapped to a database column?

Comment: How do you determine the value for `intUserId`? Is that a calculated column or it comes directly from your DB?

Comment: it come directly from my DB

Comment: Could you include the schema for your tables?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Apparently something is wrong with your entity model. Rather than showing db tables, you'd better show the entity classes - especially the one for Branch.

Comment: Added Branch entity.

Comment: There is no `intUserID` in there. Note that in your second query `u` refers to Branch.

Comment: Can u please post your tabBranchs & tabUser classes? and configuration. Something fishy with your mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to map properties that are not mapped to a database column in a Where expression. You must build the expression based on mapped properties. The intUserID I think is not mapped for that error is occurring. Hope this helps.

```
public class Branch {
    public string strName { get; set; }
    public List<Mark> markList { get; set; }
    public double dblAverage { get; set; }
    public double? dblGoal { get; set; }
    public bool bHasGoal { get; set; }
    public int intNbOfGradeForAYear { get; set; }
    public int intUserID { get; set; } //map it

    public Branch(){}

    public Branch(string branchName, double goal, int nbOfNotes,int userID) // add userID
    {
       // TODO: Complete member initialization
       this.strName = branchName;
       this.dblGoal = goal;
       bHasGoal = true;
       this.intNbOfGradeForAYear = nbOfNotes;
       this.intUserID = userID; // map it
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I build the expression on mapped properties please ?

Comment: On edit 2 map intUserID. Add property and assign it.

Comment: I've added what you have writted but it still not work , was it the complete solution?

Comment: Please try this one: var list = db.tabBranchs.Find(intBranchID); after then work with the list.

Comment: I tried, list ist now equal to null , I don't know why. I verified the two tables and list should not be null

Comment: did you use = operator instead of Equals.

Comment: Yes , I used = operator

Comment: Use IQueryable if you think ToList() will cause memory load.

Comment: I founded that if I execute  db.tabBranchs.Find(intBranchID); it's searching in intBranchID column and not in intUserID column

Comment: give there intUserID instead, if you want to look up on the column.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because intUserID participates in an FK constraint

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_tabBranchs_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([intUserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tabUser] ([intUserID])
```

Could you try this instead, just to troubleshoot

```
where u.tabUser.intUserID.Equals(userID)
```

If this works, then it is also necessary to double check if the following query is not causing an unnecessary join

Comment: I can't access to tabUser with u.tabUser because the user own the branch